# How to share bash/shell code snippets taken from command prompt with syntax coloring

Tags: bash, shell, syntax-highlighting, code-snippets, prompt

I'm looking for some way to share code snippets taken directly from command prompt.
For example:

```
plinjasa@pllzpc029 ~
$ ls

plinjasa@pllzpc029 ~
$ mkdir maindir

plinjasa@pllzpc029 ~
$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 plinjasa Domain Users 0 2010-08-26 15:22 maindir

plinjasa@pllzpc029 ~
$ cd maindir

plinjasa@pllzpc029 ~/maindir
$ touch somefile

plinjasa@pllzpc029 ~/maindir
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 plinjasa Domain Users 0 2010-08-26 15:22 somefile

plinjasa@pllzpc029 ~/maindir
$
```

There are some solutions to show this with bash syntax highlighting (as you can see) but I don't see any way to preserve prompt coloring or anything which would help to read such snippet.

Any ideas?

[EDIT] Fixed example as it caused some confusion about having FTP coloring too. It's not important

Answer (score 3):

You can capture console sessions using [script](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script). When you exit the session, there will be a file called `typescript` containing exactly what you've typed/seen on the console. You can then convert it (including console color codes) to HTML using [ANSIFilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/ansifilter/ansifilter.html). Its output is not yet perfect, but might fit your needs.

If you don't need it to be portable or if the recipient is also using a UNIX/Linux terminal, you can also just send the typescript file, which can be viewn using `cat` or `less -R` in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a utility to convert ansi colored terminal output to html. One of them is here: [ansi2html.sh](http://github.com/pixelb/scripts/blob/master/scripts/ansi2html.sh) and I found it very useful. jkramer provided solution to obtain a text file with the full log from the terminal, which can be used with ansi2html.sh, so I won't repeat it here.

Answer (score 0):

Not easy at all, because of the different prompts, separators, etc. I would, for instance, separate logically the interactions with different programs (lftp and the shell itself), and reduce the prompt to the minimum expression. That is something like:

You open the `lftp` program and do whatever:

```
$ lftp
lftp> open -u ...
Password...
...
lftp> XXX
lftp> exit
```

then you can test into your shell prompt:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
drwx....
```

This way you separate different actuations to different programs, and reducing the prompt to a small word helps identifying the program being used.

Comment: It's not what I really want. Leave FTP part. Having only bash prompt syntax-highlighting would be more than enough what I would like to have